# Execute a python script with external libraries imported using a php file

Tags: php, python

I am not able to execute a python script with external libraries imported using a php file. A simple file with system libraries(e.g. sys) executes and the output is shown in the browser but the browser shows no output while using external libraries.
1. My php file -

```
<?php
putenv('PYTHONPATH=/home/saurabh/anaconda3/bin/python3.6');
$output = `python3 script.py`;
echo $output;
?>
```

2. python file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import sys
image = Image.open("testImage2.jpeg")
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang="eng")
print(text)
```

Comment: Did you try using `shell_exec` or `exec` PHP function instead?

Comment: You may want to try using the `absolute path` to `python3` binary  (i.e.: `/usr/bin/python3` ), and `script.py` . Drop `putenv('PYTHONPATH=/home/saurabh/anaconda3/bin/python3.6');`. Also try using the `absolute path` in `Image.open("/some/absolute/path/testImage2.jpeg")`. As suggested by @Dejv, use `shell_exec` or `exec`.

Comment: Hi @Dejv, I tried all of these and they work when executing simple python scripts containing system libraries. But the browser shows no output when I try using other libraries like the ones above.

Comment: @PedroLobito, I tried these but it didn't work out.

Comment: Please describe ***it didn't work out***.

Comment: @PedroLobito I am still unable to get the output in the browser when using external python libraries.

Comment: Remember that `shell_exec` and `exec` run under the same user as `php`. Make sure they've the right permissions to create the file.

Comment: @PedroLobito The same file executes when external libraries are not used